# Can ncwa (NCO) understand missing_value

Tags: attributes, mask, netcdf, nco

I'm trying to use NCO's `ncwa` script to find out ranges for some data variables in netcdf files. However it looks like it cannot decode `missing_value` attribute by default and that is used to define the results.

For instance, I am trying to run:

```
ncwa -y min -v hs ./test.nc /tmp/min.nc
```

to find out the minimum value for variable `hs` in file `./test.nc`. The output is `-9` as shown below which is the missing_value attribute of that variable.

I tried with different files with different `missing_value` values and this is still the case. However the `_FillValue` attribute does seem to be decoded correctly by `ncwa` when present, with associated values being ignored in the results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
% ncdump /tmp/min.nc
netcdf min {
variables:
    float hs ;
        hs:standard_name = "sea_surface_wave_significant_height" ;
        hs:units = "m" ;
        hs:long_name = "Significant wave height" ;
        hs:missing_value = -9.f ;
        hs:cell_methods = "time, lat, lon: minimum" ;
data:
    hs = -9 ;
}

% ncwa --version
ncwa 4.6.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons described [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#missing_value), NCO pays attention to `_FillValue` not `missing_value`. The recommended solution is to add a `_FillValue` attribute with the same value as the `missing_value` attribute:

```
ncatted -O -a _FillValue,,o,f,1.0e36 inout.nc
```

or to rename the `missing_value` to `_FillValue`:

```
ncrename -a .missing_value,_FillValue inout.nc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charlie, it solves our issue. It is a shame missing data cannot be specified with both `_FillValue` and `missing_value` as most of the model output we handle uses the latter but renaming the attribute is an easy solution.